# Combine tables in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to combine two tables in Power BI.

I have the following two tables:

```html
<table border="1">
<tr><th>Id</th><th>Category</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>A</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>B</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>A</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>B</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>C</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>A</td></tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<table border="1">
<tr><th>Id</th><th>Value</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>10</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>20</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>10</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>30</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>20</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>30</td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td><td>10</td></tr>
</table>
```

I need to combine them as below:

```html
<table border="1">
<tr><th>Id</th><th>Category</th><th>Value</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>A</td><th>10</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>A</td><th>20</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>B</td><th>10</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>B</td><th>20</th></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>A</td><th>BLANK</th></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>B</td><th>10</th></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>B</td><th>30</th></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>C</td><th>10</th></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>C</td><th>30</th></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>A</td><th>20</th></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>A</td><th>30</th></tr>
<tr><td>5</td><td>BLANK</td><th>10</th></tr>
</table>
```

How can this be achieved using the DAX in Power BI ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you will need a distinct list of all IDs between your two tables. To get this in PowerBI, click on 'Modeling' -> 'New Table' and enter this formula.

```
IDs = DISTINCT(UNION(
    SELECTCOLUMNS(Categories, "ID", Categories[Id]), 
    SELECTCOLUMNS('Values', "ID", 'Values'[Id]))
)
```

[image: ID Table]

This table will help create a many-to-many relationship between your category table and value table.

[image: Relationship]

With that relationship in place, you can create another new table with this formula to get you results.

```
Results = SELECTCOLUMNS(NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN(NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN(IDs, Categories), 'Values'),
    "ID", IDs[ID], 
    "Category", Categories[Category], 
    "Value", 'Values'[Value]
)
```

[image: Results]

Answer (score 1):

(a Power Query, not DAX solution)

---

Add a blank query:

`= Table.NestedJoin(Table1,{"Id"},Table2,{"Id"},"Table2",JoinKind.FullOuter)`

Add a transformation step:

`= Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Table2", {"Id", "Value"}, {"Table2.Id", "Value"})`

Add step:

`= Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Table2", "NewId", each (if [Id] = null then [Table2.Id] else [Id]))`

Delete columns `Id` and `Table2.Id`.

---

Alternatively, a GUI approach via PowerBI Desktop:

- Open query editor -> Home tab
- Merge queries -> As New
- Select both tables, highlight Id column, Full outer join
- Expand the last column.
- Rename columns appropriately.
- Coalesce Id columns using the method of your choice.