# Power BI: Combine multiple tables in long format

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I want to combine 3 tables using Power BI.  This is what they currently look like.

[image: 3 tables]

I was able to combine them like this using this code:

```
Table.Combine({"Table1","Table2","Table3"}, {"Store","Name","Year"})
```

[image: my code so far]

I would like to transform them in a long format like this

[image: desired outcome]

but combine only works for columns of the same name.  I tried 'merge' but it changed the format to wide which I don't want.  I tried 'transpose' but it made my table look like this which is not what I want:

```
store1 store1 store1
mary   john   roger
1968   2020   1984....
```

Does anyone have any advice? I checked online [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591669/combine-tables-in-power-bi), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46273221/power-bi-combine-multiple-tables-into-one) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58807162/combining-table-information-using-power-bi) but my case seems different.

Thank you in advance for any help or if you can point me to a similar question that was answered.

Here is my data in markdown format:

```
Store   Name    Year    Fav fruit   Fav veg
Store1  Mary    1968    apple       carrot
Store1  John    2020    pear        turnip
Store1  Roger   1984    plum        potato

Store   Name    Year    Height  Weight
Store2  Mary    1968    5ft     100kg
Store2  John    2020    6ft     90kg
Store2  Bob     1996    7ft     80kg

Store   Name    Year    Fav drink   Fav candy
Store3  Mary    1968    pepsi       kitkat
Store3  John    2020    coke        m&m
Store3  Henry   1978    fanta       hershey
```

Comment: Please paste your sample data in markdown format so it can be copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
let Source = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Table1, {"Store", "Name", "Year"}, "Question", "Answer") & 
    Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Table2, {"Store", "Name", "Year"}, "Question", "Answer") &
    Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Table3, {"Store", "Name", "Year"}, "Question", "Answer")
in Source
```

[image]

Comment: Elegant as always. Upvoted.

Comment: My editor has default code from pulling in the excel file ( see my other comment above),  when I tried to edit it showed an error  'expression error: a cyclic reference was encountered during evaluation.  Thanks

Comment: if you can use this code Table.Combine({"Table1","Table2","Table3"}, {"Store","Name","Year"}) then you can use my code  Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Table1, {"Store", "Name", "Year"}, "Question", "Answer") & 
    Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Table2, {"Store", "Name", "Year"}, "Question", "Answer") &
    Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Table3, {"Store", "Name", "Year"}, "Question", "Answer")

Comment: Thank you for that clue! Solution for others: First make sure Power BI does not automatically add any relationships.  It printed the error because it added a relationship between the tables by default so I deleted the relationships.  After: click each table, click 'unpivot other columns; instead of table1, Table2 or Table3, go to Advanced Editor and find most recent source (for me it was 'Promoted Headers' and add everything from  ,{"Store", "Name", "Year"}, "Question", "Answer") onwards.   Do that for each table.  After that, click 'Append' to append all three tables and it works!!  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

After combining, you'll have something that looks like this:

```
let
    get_tbl = (tablename as text) as table => Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=tablename]}[Content],
    table1 = get_tbl("Table1"),
    table2 = get_tbl("Table2"),
    table3 = get_tbl("Table3"),
    result = Table.Combine({table1,table2,table3})
in
    result
```

[image]

Select the Store, Name and Year columns, then use Transform > Unpivot Other Columns:

[image]

This is the result:

[image]

You can then edit the code to change the Attribute and Value columns to Question and Answer:

```
let
    get_tbl = (tablename as text) as table => Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=tablename]}[Content],
    table1 = get_tbl("Table1"),
    table2 = get_tbl("Table2"),
    table3 = get_tbl("Table3"),
    combined = Table.Combine({table1,table2,table3}),
    result = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(combined, {"Store", "Name", "Year"}, "Question", "Answer")
in
    result
```

[image]

EDIT: try this:

```
let 
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("c:\data.xslx"),null,true), 
    tbl = (tablename) => 
        let t = Source{[Item=tablename,Kind="sheet"]}[Data] 
        in Table.PromotedHeaders(t, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    combined = Table.Combine({tbl("Store1"),tbl("Store1"),tbl("Store1")}),
    result = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(combined, {"Store", "Name", "Year"}, "Question", "Answer")
in
    result
```

Comment: How do I add it to my Advanced editor?  My editor looks like this    let Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(c:\data.xslx),null,true),  store1_sheet = Source{[Item="Store1",Kind="sheet"]}[Data], #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromotedHeaders(store1_sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]) in #"Promoted Headers"

Comment: @ithoughtso please see edit to my answer

Comment: Thank you for your comment! it also helped me understand the unpivot part of the code.  It turns out the error was because Power BI added table relationships by default and I had to delete them first.

Comment: Both you and horseyRide helped me understand the error and how PowerBI works.  I wish I could give both of you the solution but I think Stack overflow only lets me give it to one